# Campo "__v" em todos os documentos de uma coleção

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Todos os meus documentos em um banco de dados do MongoDB possuem um campo `__v`, o que significa?

```
> db.speeds.find({}).limit(2).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586826f700890738a5e8cb3d"),
    "remoteId" : 1,
    "first" : ObjectId("586826f700890738a5e8cb3a"),
    "second" : ObjectId("586826f700890738a5e8cb3b"),
    "third" : ObjectId("586826f700890738a5e8cb3c"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5868270c6a16ce38d79f8af7"),
    "remoteId" : 2,
    "first" : ObjectId("5868270c6a16ce38d79f8af4"),
    "second" : ObjectId("5868270c6a16ce38d79f8af5"),
    "third" : ObjectId("5868270c6a16ce38d79f8af6"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Você usa o Mongoose para fazer o CRUD?

Comment: Sim, uso o mongoose.

Comment: Eu não lembro o que é exatamente, mas tem alguma coisa a ver com a versão do registro. De uma lida nesse post aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495891/what-is-the-v-field-in-mongodb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__v` é uma chave de versionamente presente em cada documento criado através do [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).

Essa chave é incrementada quando acontece uma alteração na estrutura de uma coleção que já possua documentos, exemplo:

```js
{
    "_id": String,
    "title": String,
    "description": String
}
```

Alterado para:

```js
{
    "_id": String,
    "title": String,
    "description": String,
    "comments": Array
}
```

Agora todos documentos que forem inseridos terão a chave de versionamento `__v: 1`.

### Configuração

É possível desativar o versionamento na criação do `Schema`.

```js
new mongoose.Schema({}, {
    versionKey: false
});
```

Ou alterar o nome da chave.

```js
new mongoose.Schema({}, {
    versionKey: '_version'
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey